# jQuery loading external page (cross domain) into Div element

Tags: jquery, mobile

I want to load an external page ( page is not part of my app). Basically I want to load a webpage e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

I want to display this asp page into div element which is on my page. I want to use jQuery Mobile / Javascript. I have tried something like -

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp",
    success: function(data){
            $("div").html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, throwerror) 
             {
                      alert('response' + xhr.responseText);}
    });
```

Or

```
    $.load("http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp", function(data){
            $("div").html(data);
    }
```

I don't want to use IFrame, i think its not supported in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use iframe. That's the correct way of doing this!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does jQuery Mobile supports iFrame ?

Comment: I agree with Namrata. I think jquery mobile supports iframes. this may helps you. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to request data from another domain because it is not allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, unless that domain allows requests from your domain. You will have to use an iFrame or post a request from your server which could fetch the contents of the URL and spit it back to you.

Answer (score 0):

you said "jQuery Mobile", I think you can do it with jquery mobile's config:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/how-configure-phonegap-cordova.html

If you use phonegap (cordova), you can also do it:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide