# a php site that creates a page based on a users click

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm not even 100% sure how to ask this question, but I will try my best...

So, take youtube. You've got this:

```
URL/watch?v=Video_URL_Here
```

While on this video, you decide to click a video in the related on the right-side.
While doing that, the page refreshes, and instantly jumps to that video.

I have the basic concept down:

```
> Create a variable.
    $var;

> User: *Clicks First Video*
    $var = Video_One;  // Pulls from mySQL-DB

> Open a new page (ex: URL/watch?v=Video_ONE)
     PHP: >Creates a whole new page for the video.<

> User: *clicks new video*
    $var = Video_Two;

> Open a new page (ex: URL/watch?v=Video_TWO)
     PHP: >Working more magic.<
```

However, I'm having a hard time actually doing this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or explain how it works?

It would be very appreciated.

Comment: hm it seems a normal <a href... tag with php controller which gets the request and dynamicly build the html

Comment: You might want to pick up a book on php programming at your local library.  Work through the examples.  This will pay dividends on figuring out how things work.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you just want to understand how it works (the youtube example and any other similar site), or you want to know how to make your own site with similar functionality?

Comment: Similar functionality. I figured if someone explain a little about how youtube works, I could figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer with a very general and oversimplified example

actually, more than having a unique "$var" that changes every time you click on a video (on your example), it is more like the page already knows where to go for each link (or click), that is, every video already has a link associated, with the corresponding url.

all this is done BEFORE the page loads. (there are ways to make it after, but that is another matter).

Just to give a quick example (it may not be exactly how youtube works, it is just an example)

Lets say you store each videos name, description, rating, etc on a database table.

e.g.

```
video1name, url1, description1, etc1
video2name, url2, description2, etc2
video3name, url3, description3, etc3
```

also assume each video has already related videos stored somewhere (the videos which would show on the right side) (imagine they are in the same table, each video having their own "related videos" associated.

so, when putting the page together, via PHP (in this case), what the code does is, read the data from the database, so it will know what it will "paint", at that point, it stores such data in variables, and using those vairables, it is ready to build the page, using such data.

imagine you say "i need 5 videos here, those videos are this, this other .... etc"
so php will read those 5 videos info form the database, AND knowing their data, it already "knows" what will the specific url for each video will be.

it only has to build links for each video, each having it's speciffic url.

e.g.

```
[some html]
...
<a href="myvid1url" > ...</a>
<a href="myvid2url" > ...</a>
<a href="myvid2url" > ...</a>
...
[the rest of html]
```

the only thing php is doing, is creating HTML dynamically, based on that data, and once it finishes, it sends it to the browser, which only has to "paint" plain html, all of which is already filled with the particular urls, names, etc for each part.

This is a VERY generalized example, but i hope you get the idea.

The most important part is to understand that most of the time, pages are already "built" before being displayed, once loaded, they already "know" what to do when you click somewhere, etc.

Of course, you can add interactive functionality, using javascript, ajax, etc, and that MAY change the page already loaded, but that is another concept.

I think you should first tell us what your experience with programming is, or if you have only made plain simple htmls pages or anything, so we could give you better advice.

have fun!

Comment: It's now a lot more clear. I really like how thorough you were with your answer. I really appreciate all the help, friend. In future questions, I will make sure to explain better with my understanding.

Comment: You are welcome, just be sure to be more specific on what you want or need, and also it would help if you mention what you already know or tried. For example, you may already know HTML, javascript, and even basic PHP, but since you don't mention it, we can just guess. I recommend to try a PHP tutorial, so you can understand the concept of dynamic pages, which is precisely what you seem to need. Good luck! and feel free to ask any doubts, that is what SO is for, (it has helped me a lot!) just try to always be specific and clear =P.

Answer (score 2):

The way YouTube works is using `$_GET` variables. That's what the `?v=` is. It's taking in the `v` variable and checking the database for a video with that video id. The way they create the new page is by fetching each of the values corresponding to the id that was passed in the url,  then putting that data in each of the page sections.

Comment: Awesome. How would I go about replicating something like this? I understand it, just not how to do it. I suppose my question would be:

How do I create a global variable that changes per a users click, while using $_GET?

    URL/watchVideo.php?v=URL

Comment: you do NOT need global variables (not PHP ones, because you CANNOT have php code once the page is loaded), in any case, you would need javascript variables if you need them to change ONCE the page is loaded. but for anything that needs to be "there" BEFORE, you do it in PHP's side. please read my answer for details

Comment: @DiegoDD you made a very thorough answer, so good job. I was trying to answer his question in a way that would solve the problem, not a way that worked exactly how he wanted. My solution would work for what he is thinking of (as far as I know), so I am going to leave it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery and have the second video load in a frame, iframe, div, table, new window, etc (depending on the data source, of course)

External sources (depending)
[jQuery loading external page (cross domain) into Div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139949/jquery-loading-external-page-cross-domain-into-div-element)

Local content sources
[Load HTML page dynamically into div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735762/load-html-page-dynamically-into-div-with-jquery)

For external data loading you could get all creative and run a curl to save the data locally, parse it for what you need and then serve that locally